# Label Maker or printer for bulk production of product description stickers?

Tags: printer

Need to print about 1000 stickers/month with the product description. Should I purchase a label maker or a printer?

In the past couple of years, about 3 printers I've bought have stopped working. I am looking for something reliable and cost-efficient.

Comment: Monochrome and text/barcode only? A dot-matrix printer with sprocket feed may be all you need.

Comment: Hey Mick, yes monochrome text is all I am after. Thanks. Can you please provide a link to this printer? I'll do some research of my own.

Comment: You might add which printers you have used to avoid duplication. For commercial production use, I would recommend a [Zebra Printer](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/printers.html) if you can find one that fits your needs.

Comment: How about avery labels on 8.5" by 11 sheets and then using the avery template in MS office or libreoffice?  Laser printers last a long time, hp laserjet 4000,4050,4100,4200,4250 have all lasted 10+ years.  Even modern M600,601,604, and etc run more than that in a month.